# scale_fill_manual not working with stat_function in loops

Tags: r

I am having issue making scale_fill_manual to work with stat_function performed in loops. Below is a dummy dataset and ideally I want the legend to match the shade and line colors of the respective distributions (three density functions in this case). Does anyone have good suggestions? Below are what I tried but each has their own problems:

###Dummy Dataset:

```
x<-seq(-200, 200, by=2)
means<-c(50, 100, -100)
sds<-c(70, 50, 40)
lamdas<-c(35, 35, 30)
colors<-c("red", "blue", "green")
data<-rnorm(300, mean=0, sd=50)
```

###Example1: No legend is outputted in this case:

```
p1<-ggplot(data.frame(data), aes(x=data))+geom_histogram(aes(x=data, y=..density..))
for (i in 1:length(means)){
    p1<-p1+stat_function(fun=dnorm, n=1000, args=list(means[i], sds[i]), aes(color=colors[i]), color=colors[i], geom="area", fill=colors[i], alpha = .2)
}
p1+ggtitle("Test Adding Legend")+theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
scale_fill_manual(c("test1", "test2", "test3"))
print(p1)
```

###Example2: legend not matching color in loop

```
p1<-ggplot(data.frame(data), aes(x=data))+geom_histogram(aes(x=data, y=..density..))
for (i in 1:length(means)){
    p1<-p1+stat_function(fun=dnorm, n=1000, args=list(means[i], sds[i]), aes(color=colors[i]), geom="area", fill=colors[i], alpha = .2)
}
p1+ggtitle("Test Adding Legend")+theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
scale_fill_manual(c("test1", "test2", "test3"))
print(p1)
```

###Example3: Line color not matching shade color and legend not filled

```
p1<-ggplot(datadf, aes(x=datadup, color=factor(meansdup), fill=factor(meansdup)))
for (i in 1:length(means)){
    sdf<-datadf[datadf$meansdup == means[i],]
    p1<-p1+geom_histogram(aes(x=sdf$datadup, y=..density..), fill=NA, color="black")+
stat_function(fun=dnorm, n=1000, args=list(means[i], sds[i]), geom="area", fill=colors[i], alpha = .2)
}
p1+ggtitle("Test Adding Legend")+theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
scale_fill_manual(values=colors, c("test1", "test2", "test3"))
```

Ideally we want the legend to match the shade and line colors of the distributions. Is there a way to do so? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ggplot is quoting its arguments, so when you type `aes(fill=colors[i])` it is literally interpreted as a value called "color[i]". You want of course to use the content of the vector `colors` at position `i`, so you need to unquote with `!!`.

```
p1<-ggplot(data.frame(data), aes(x=data))+
  geom_histogram(aes(x=data, y=..density..), bins=30)
for (i in 1:length(means)){
  p1<-p1+
    stat_function(fun=dnorm,
                  n=1000, args=list(means[i], sds[i]),
                  aes(fill=!!colors[i], color=!!colors[i]), geom="area",
                  alpha = .2)
}
```

Of course you need to put that inside `aes()` else it's not considered as a meaningful factor, merely an some decoration, so there is no point in making a legend for decoration.

Now the problem is rather that you have two legends, one for fill the other for color. You can remove whichever you want:

```
p1+
  scale_color_discrete(guide=FALSE)
```

[image]